# How to pass an argument with no value to CMake?

Tags: cmake

In CMake, can I pass a variable with no value as a parameter, and check if it is provided?

```
cmake -DPAR1=123 -DPAR2

# CMakeLists.txt
if (PAR2)
    message("PAR2 detected")
else()
    message("PAR2 not detected")
endif()
```

With this code I get the error:

```
Parse error in command line argument: -DPAR2
Should be: VAR:type=value
CMake Error: No cmake script provided.
CMake Error: Problem processing arguments. Aborting.
```

Comment: What is the context for passing an empty variable like this? Can you pass an empty string `-DPAR2=""` or something similar instead?

Comment: @squareskittles - Yes, I could. But for a binary parameter I would prefer to either pass it with something like `-DPAR2`, which would mean `true`, or omit it, which would mean `false`.

Comment: CMake expects the `-D` arguments to be of the form `type=value`. That's what the error message is telling you. You could set PAR2 equal to anything `-DPAR2=anything` to be your `true` case, then omit it for `false`.

Comment: Is there any command option other than `-D` which allows to do it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But as @Angew hinted at, you may be looking for the `DEFINED` unary test for your if-statement: `if(DEFINED PAR2)`

Comment: If you want to **unset** the variable (make it *undefined*), use `-UPAR2` instead.

Comment: @squareskittles - The problem is that the error I get is generated from parsing cmake's parameters, even before my `CMakeLists.txt` is opened.

Comment: You will likely need to change your CMake parameters regardless, as `-DPAR2` by itself is not valid. I'm just trying to suggest alternative ways to approach what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html) CMake command line argument is required to be of the form `var=value`. But, one way to simulate a boolean or `#ifdef` is to pass a valid value (which can be anything you want) for your `true` case:

```
cmake -DPAR1=123 -DPAR2=True
```

and omit the variable altogether in the `false` case:

```
cmake -DPAR1=123
```

Finally, in your `CMakeLists.txt` file, change your if-statement to use [`DEFINED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) to check for existence of the `PAR2` variable:

```
if (DEFINED PAR2)
    message("PAR2 detected")
else()
    message("PAR2 not detected")
endif()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that even if you somehow managed to pass in nothing (e.g. by passing an empty string), it would not do what you want, as `if(PAR2)` would then evaluate to a false value.

If you want to use such conditionals as `if(PAR2)`, you have to give `PAR2` a truthy value, such as `1`, `Y`, `ON`, or `TRUE`:

```
cmake -DPAR1=123 -DPAR2=ON
```

Comment: Do you mean that in CMake there is nothing like an `#ifdef`?

Comment: @Pietro Yes, there is. `if(DEFINED PAR2)`.